# Python - How to get inner class text in beautifulsoup (TripAdvisor)

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get price of all the hotels in a particular area in a particular date range in TripAdvisor from python web scrape program. My program load the site with selenium select date range and when parse the data to BeautifulSoup.
Price data is located within inner classes in the site.
[Inspect element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eRiHw.jpg)

I am using this code and giving me ResultSet object has no attribute error.

```
html = browser.page_source
textobj = BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
text1=textobj.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'vr_listing'})
for item in text1:
     foo=item.find_all('div', attrs={'class' : 'price'})
     price=foo.text.strip()
     print(price)
```

Using Python 3.7
Can't figure out what to do.

Answer (score 0):

It would be great if you can provide the link that you are using so that we can reproduce the issue. But can you try this line of code:

```
html = browser.page_source
textobj = BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
prices = textobj.findAll('div', {'class':'price'}).text

for price in prices:
    print(price)

'''
text1=textobj.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'vr_listing'})
for item in text1:
     foo=item.find_all('div', attrs={'class' : 'price'})
     price=foo.text.strip()
     print(price)
'''
```

Comment: Here is my full python script
https://drive.google.com/open?id=18NK8fTbVA6JZkug_UD1PrrGPshkw2kFy

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
 foo = item.find_all('div', attrs={'class' : 'price'})
 price = foo.text.strip()
```

`find_all()` returns a `resultSet` (an iterable over a collection of tags), not a single tag. If you expect to have one single matching tag in `item`, use `item.find(...)` instead:

```
 foo = item.find('div', attrs={'class' : 'price'})
 price = foo.text.strip()
```

else iterate over the resultset:

```
 foos = item.find_all('div', attrs={'class' : 'price'})
 prices = [foo.text.strip() for foo in foos]
```